# Why doesn't width inherit work but width:100% work?

Tags: css, styles

I was creating a simple menu with some styling but I have a question, I was trying to get the **wrapper** (the white background one in the middle which contains **title** and **nav_bar**) to have the width inherited from its parent- the **container** (the one with the blue background), but when I set the width of **wrapper** to "inherit", it doesn't inherit from it, but after I change it to "100%", it does inherit from the container, why is it? Can someone explain this to me?

Thank you anyone in advance, I really appreciate your help.

Here is the code that I wrote:

HTML:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Menu bar best practice</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="navbar_example.css" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="global_header">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="title"><p>title</p></div>
                <nav id="nav_bar">
                    <p>nav_bar</p>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
@font-face {
font-family: Roboto;
src: url(Roboto-Light.ttf);
}

#global_header {
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background: grey;
overflow: hidden;
}

#container {
width: 70%;
height: inherit;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
background-color:  blue;
}

#wrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
margin: 0;
background-color: white;
}

#title {
width: 20%;
height: inherit;
margin-right: 5%;
background-color: pink;
float: left;
}

#nav_bar {
width: 75%;
height: inherit;
float: right;
background-color: black;
}

p {
color: red;
}
```

and here is the result I got

[image]

Comment: Your HTML structure would be useful.

Comment: okay I'll edit it ASAP :D